# Ember CLI Array Controller not sorting through each loop

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I can't get sortProperties to work from an array controller. I think it's because the model that the controller needs to sort is not the model that it receives by default in Ember CLI.

The posts resource defined in **router.js**:

```js
export default Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', function() { 
    this.route('index', {path: '/'});
    this.route('new');
    this.route('full', {path: '/:id'});
});
```

The model hook is defined in **routes/posts/index.js**:

```js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('post');
  },
});
```

My model for a single post (**models/post.js**)

```js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'), 
  category: DS.attr('string'),  
  created_at: DS.attr('date'), 
  
)}
```

My template displays the list of posts using an {{#each}} helper
(**templates/posts/index.hbs**):

The inner contents of the each helper is contained in a component named 'blog-list'.

```html
{{#each model as |post|}}
  {{blog-list model=post}}
{{/each}}
```

The list of posts displays fine.

I have added code to sort the list by the title property (**controllers/posts/index.js**):

```js
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['title'],
  sortAscending: true,
});
```

I'm not sure why, but the title column is not being sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate over `controller` instead of `model` in your template:

```
{{#each controller as |post|}}
  {{blog-list model=post}}
{{/each}}
```

`ArrayController` is deprecated, by the way.